# How to set CSS of one element depending on another element having a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a sidebar menu on my website that opens and closes.

When the sidebar is open I add an additional class called 'active' to the menu button which triggers the menu.

When this menu button element has the class 'active' & screen width is > 768px, I want to set the padding on the element with class 'container-fluid'.

I currently do this with coffeescript/javascript:

```
@setPaddingIfMenuOpen = () ->
  console.log 'set padding if menu open called from layout coffee'
  if $(window).width() > 768
    if $('.show-left').hasClass 'active' 
      padding = 280
      $('#main > .container-fluid').css 'padding-left', padding
    else 
      $('#main > .container-fluid').css 'padding-left', '25px'
  else 
    $('#main > .container-fluid').css 'padding-left', '25px'
```

But I was wondering if I could achieve the same thing with pure CSS?

Here is a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/685Vv/5/

Once you click the open menu button and the element #showLeft also has class 'active, see if you can get the attribute 'padding-left: 100px' added to the element with class 'main'. And then if the attribute #showLeft does not have the class 'active' then the attribute padding-left should be changed to 'padding-left: 0px'

Comment: i think you need a DOM Node Events Knowledge 

http://davidwalsh.name/dom-events-javascript
https://www.google.com.eg/#q=event+when+something+changes+on+the+dom+javascript

Comment: Since we don't know the markup structure, it isn't possible to say if there is a combination of combinators that will do what you want.

Comment: do you have any jsfiddle for your question?

Comment: Yes here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/685Vv/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)** in case you are able to apply your `.active` class (or any other class) to some shared parent element - `body` probably - as well (in case your markup has to stay the way it is you're out of luck I guess).

So in case an expanded side menu would also result in `body.side-menu-active` you could just do:

```
#main > .container-fluid{
  padding-left: 25px;
}
@media all and (min-width: 768px){
  .slide-menu-active #main > .container-fluid{
    padding-left: 280px;
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm i am trying that and it is not really working. So I applied .slide-menu-active to the body class once the slide menu is open. Then in the CSS media query I do '.slide-menu-active #main > .container-fluid' But this is the css select for an element #main that also has class .slide-menu-active. It does not seem to be targeting .container-fluid

Comment: oops I think the only issue was that by mistake I was using max-width instead of min-with! sorry about that I think this is a good solution and will work!